# Programmatically change value of Color Set in xcassets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have my iOS app's colors called out as Color Sets in an asset catalog (xcassets) file.

At runtime I'd like to be able to change the values of these Color Sets. Is this possible? and if so, how?

I've had no luck finding a way to do this.

Comment: A color set — indeed, an asset catalog as a whole — is not a thing as far as your running code is concerned. Thus, there is nothing to change the "value" of programmatically at runtime; the question is meaningless. This sounds like an x-y problem; what are you _really_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to swap out my entire color pallet at runtime, without having to change each individual UI element in code.

Comment: Prepare multiple colors and just designate in code which one you want at which time. No need to change the name or value of anything, just change which color you _use_. Simple example: if you wanted to use red instead of green, you would not change the meaning of green to be red, or change the name of red to be green; you would use red (itself) where you had been using green (itself).

Comment: Thanks, that's why I wanted to swap out the colors themselves though—I don't want to manually change the color of every UI object in code. I want to be able to assign a color such as "lightAccent" in storyboard, to any elements that need it, and then assign new values to "lightAccent" in code. I'm trying to figure out how to do this. Is there a way to get a color to show up in the storyboard other than using xcasset color sets? I think that's what I need to know.

Comment: @cmilr, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: any solution I want to change my asset catalog color with API response color

Comment: Any Solution? @cmilr

Comment: Any solutions found yet? @cmilr

Comment: @cmilr, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't change colors in an asset catalog. If you want to change those colors at runtime you need to fetch the initial colors from the asset catalog, store it somewhere else (e.g. UserDefaults) and modify those.

Comment: D.Mika can you explain it a little more Please? Ho to do the whole process which you mentioned?? how to fetch initial colours, and how to modify them or replace them later??

Comment: you can get the colour from assets by using "UIColor(named: "your color name from assets")"